# C# Escolher caixa de Email ao enviar

Tags: c#, .net, envio-de-email

Eu queria saber se há alguma forma de mandar e-mails para as outras caixas de entrada, por exemplo a do gmail

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No momento meu código para envio de e-mails é esse:

```
using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpHost"], 587))
{
     smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpClient"],
                                                    WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpClientPassword"]);
     smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

     smtpClient.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
     {
        smtpClient.Dispose();
        ((MailMessage)e.UserState).Dispose();
     };

     await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(model.GetMessage());
}
```

Existe alguma classe, propriedade no client, qualquer coisa que eu possa fazer para atingir este objetivo?

Comment: O objectivo é enviar um email para uma conta de gmail? Se sim, então é utilizar esse código que tens, mudando o destinatário no objecto da mensagem. ps: estás a fazer isso em MVC, certo?

Comment: @RenatoAfonso O objetivo é : Ao invés de enviar para **caixa de entrada**, enviar para **Atualizações**, ou qualquer outra.

Comment: Por código, penso que não tem forma. Tens de configurar na tua própria caixa de email uma regra para redirecionar os emails com um determinado formato para essa zona específica.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso tens alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Se for no gmail, basta ir às definições, e tens lá uma opção de filtros e endereços bloqueados, clicas para criar um novo filtro, defines as regras pelas quais queres capturar o tipo de email que queres, e depois defines a acção (para onde vais querer mandar esse email)